# Is it possible to download an image from Google Drive with our Email (Gmail) and password using SpringBoot + Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I try downloading an image or a file from Google Drive using Spring Boot with Java. But it is expecting Google credentials. I don't have any credentials handy. So can we download our own Google Drive image or file using our email (Gmail and password) to bypass the credentials? I will attach the code am using currently, and please let me know if I can replace the credentials with Gmail or any other way...

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream downloadFile(String fileId) throws IOException{
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                        requestInitializer)
                        .setApplicationName("Drive Samples")
                        .build();
try{
         OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         service.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
         return (ByteArrayOutputStream) outputStream;

}catch(GoogleJsonResponseException e){
   System.err.print("unable to move file: " e.getDetails());
   throw e;
}

}
```

Please check and share if any other ways other than Google credentials are there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me summarize: You want your code use an email/password of a GMAIL address to get a credential, and use that credential to download file in Google Drive?

Comment: Hi, @guillaumeblaquiere anything would be fine. 1. If possible generate the credentials using our Gmail. we can use it. OR 2. without any credentials if we can connect to google drive using Gmail? Is this possible? then either of the ones I can use.

Comment: If you're looking for an option to use Google API without pre-created application credentials then there aren't any options. Other way is to make web scraper which will be blocked in some time after

Comment: Hi, @Irremediable Thanks for the reply. I say If I don't have access to Gcloud download the service JSON key and use it in the program. For that case, I have my Gmail address with that if there is any possibility then I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

To access a Google api in this case the google drive API you must register your application with Google.

Then you can use Oauth2 to request consent to access private user data in this case an image owner by a user.

Its not possible to access the google API without first registering your application and then crediting credentials json

no you can't use an email

Comment: Thank you so much, @Linda Lawton - DaImTo for the reply. Thanks for the insights again.